# Grails 3 fields plugin -> Customizing Field Rendering issue

Tags: grails, gradle, war, grails-plugin

I'm using Grails 3 and using a template `_displayWidget.gsp` to show certain parts of the show view differently.

All works fine when running the application directly, but when I build the war (using gradle assemble) and deploy this (on a tomcat 7) my own written `_displayWidget.gsp` is not used anymore. Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: what happens if you use `grails war` to build your war file?

Comment: this seems to help (at first check, cause I made some changes as work around)

Answer (score 0):

Use `grails war` to create your war.